# Random Variable Notation and the interpretation of $X_n (\omega)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems

I am currently reading notes for a probability class I am taking and am having trouble with notation.

Let Ω = [0, 1], and let P be the uniform probability measure on Ω so that P([a, b]) = b − a

There are two notations for a sequence of random variables:

$X_n$ ~ $n \cdot Bernoulli(\frac{1}{n})$ and $X_n (\omega)$ = $n \cdot \mathbb{1}_\omega \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$. I was told that notation one and two are different, as the second notation means that the $X_n$'s are not independent. I am not really sure what this means. Could someone please help me clarify the difference between these two notations?

Is the reason $X_n$'s aren't independent for equation 2 because the $\omega$ value we have for each of the $X_n$'s are the same? So for example if $\omega$ = $\frac{1}{2}$ for $X_1$, we have that $X_1 (\omega)$ = $1$. Then this means that $X_2 (\omega)$ = $2$?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps consult the definition of "independent" when asking whether some random variables are independent.  The notation $X_n \sim n \cdot \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{n})$ does not specify what dependence there is among the r.v.s.

Comment: I see thanks. Does that mean that the second notation is dependent?

Comment: The second notation $X_n(\omega)=n \cdot 1_\omega \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ is nonsense. It presumably means $X_n(\omega)=n\cdot 1_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}(\omega)\,.$ Exercise: is that, too, a Bernoulli random variable multiplied by $n\,$? Are $X_n$ and $X_m$ for $m\not=n$ uncorrelated? Or perhaps simpler: do they satisfy $\mathbb E[X_nX_m]=\mathbb E[X_n]\mathbb E[X_m]\,?$